# Kotlin Supabase - Error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.guilherme.supabase.ProductRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, supabase

I am trying to create a simple project that shows the content of table on my app screen, but I am missing something, it is always returning an error when I try to run the app. I am following the steps from Framework Quickstarts - Use Supabase with Android Kotlin page -> https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/kotlin.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContent {
ProductListScreen()
}
}
}
```

CoreApplication.kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class CoreApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
super.onCreate()

}
```

}

Product.kt

```
data class Product(
val productId: String,
val name: String,
val description: String,
val price: Double,
val image: String,
val category: String,
val nutrition: String,
val _id: Int,
)
```

ProductDto.kt:

```
@Serializable
data class ProductDto(
@SerialName("productid")
val productId: String,
@SerialName("name")
val name: String,
@SerialName("description")
val description: String,
@SerialName("price")
val price: Double,
@SerialName("image")
val image: String,
@SerialName("category")
val category: String,
@SerialName("nutrition")
val nutrition: String,
@SerialName("_id")
val _id: Int,
)
```

ProductRepository.kt:

```
val client = createSupabaseClient(
supabaseUrl = "https://xyzcompany.supabase.co",
supabaseKey = "public-anon-key"
) {
install(Postgrest)
}

interface ProductRepository {
suspend fun getProducts(): List<ProductDto>
}

class ProductRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val postgrest: Postgrest,
) : ProductRepository {
override suspend fun getProducts(): List<ProductDto> {
val result = client.postgrest["products"]
.select().decodeList<ProductDto>()
// Handle result data for next step
return result
}
}
```

RepositoryModule.kt

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindProductRepository(impl: ProductRepositoryImpl): ProductRepository
}
```

ProductListViewModel.kt:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductListViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {

private val _productList = MutableStateFlow<List<Product>?>(listOf())
val productList: Flow<List<Product>?> = _productList

init {
getProducts()
}

fun getProducts() {
viewModelScope.launch {
val products = productRepository.getProducts()
_productList.emit(products?.map { it -> it.asDomainModel() })
}
}

private fun ProductDto.asDomainModel(): Product {
return Product(
productId = this.productId,
name = this.name,
price = this.price,
image = this.image,
description = this.description,
category = this.category,
nutrition = this.nutrition,
_id = this._id
)
}
}
```

ProductListScreen.kt:

```
@Composable
fun ProductListScreen(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
viewModel: ProductListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
val productList = viewModel.productList.collectAsState(initial = listOf()).value
if (!productList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
LazyColumn(
modifier = modifier.padding(24.dp),
contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp)
) {
items(productList) { product ->
ProductListItem(
product = product,
modifier = modifier,
)
}
}
}
}

@Composable
fun ProductListItem(product: Product, modifier: Modifier) {
Column {
Text(text = "Name: ${product.name}")
Text(text = "Description: ${product.description}")
Text(text = "Price: ${product.price}")
Text(text = "Image: ${product.image}")
Text(text = "Category: ${product.category}")
Text(text = "Nutrition: ${product.nutrition}")
}
}
```

Error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.guilherme.supabase.ProductRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements CoreApplication_GeneratedInjector,
^

Missing binding usage:
com.guilherme.supabase.ProductRepository is injected at
com.guilherme.supabase.ProductListViewModel(productRepository)
com.guilherme.supabase.ProductListViewModel is injected at
com.guilherme.supabase.ProductListViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Ma
```

build.gradle.kts(app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.guilherme.supabase"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.guilherme.supabase"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Dagger-Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48.1")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    ksp ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48.1")

    // Supabase
    val supabase_version = "1.3.2"
    implementation ("io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:postgrest-kt:$supabase_version")

    // Ktor
    val ktor_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")


}
```

build.gradle.kts

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13" apply false
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48.1")
    }
}
```